# How to show GRUB after install Ubuntu over Windows 8?

Tags: installation, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I installed Windows 8 **and after that** I installed Ubuntu. This are my partition now:

- 70Gb --> **Windows 8**
- 50Gb --> **Ubuntu 12.10**
- 100Mb --> UEFI
- 300Mb --> Recovery

I installed the GRUB on `/dev/sda`. Then, after GRUB not showing up and booting directly into Windows 8, I turned the laptop off and booted again into Ubuntu LiveCD and ran the **Boot-repair** utility, it give me [this information](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1524701/) but it didn't solved the problem.

My Laptop still boots directly into Windows 8, without GRUB or Ubuntu even showing up.

Comment: ... and uefi is turned off?

Comment: Press f12 and select ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

**Install Boot-Repair on ubuntu by following steps**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the following screenshots:

***Method 1***

- **Click on the advanced options**

[image: Initial screen]

- **Tick the options shown below**

[image: advanced option]

- **Change the tab to Grub Location Tab and Tick The options Shown in the figure**

[image]

**Press Apply and Reboot the system**

***Method 2***

- Select the recommended Boot repair options as shown in the first screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that one of two things is happening:

- Ubuntu didn't completely install its boot loader, in which case you need to use the `efibootmgr` program from a Linux emergency disc to finish the job. Overall, this seems a bit unlikely, but it's the possibility that I hope is correct.
- Your firmware is one of the many broken designs that violates the EFI spec and boots Windows despite the fact that another boot loader is correctly configured as the default.

There are several possible solutions, depending on which of these things is happening and your personal preferences for how to proceed. These include:

- Boot a Linux emergency disc *in EFI mode* and type `sudo efibootmgr -c -p 2 -d /dev/sda -l "\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" -L "Ubuntu"` to re-register Ubuntu's boot loader with the ESP. You may need to change `/dev/sda` if your method of booting changes what is currently `/dev/sda` to something else. Depending on the disc you use, you may also need to install `efibootmgr` and perhaps do an `insmod efivars` before using `efibootmgr`. This method will work only if my first hypothesis about what is wrong is correct.
- Run the Boot Repair tool and tell it to fix things. This has a high probability of working and is easy to do, but it will likely do so in a way that could create further problems down the road. If it doesn't work, it will become harder to disentangle everything.
- Mount the EFI System Partition (ESP; your /dev/sda2), move the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` file down one level (so that it's `EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi`), and then copy `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to `EFI/Microsofot/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. This is the key thing that Boot Repair would do, but done in a slightly different way. You'll then need to modify your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file before you'll be able to boot Windows. I'm not sure if the `update-grub` script will pick up the change automatically. It might, but if not, you'll need to create a new Windows entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` for the new location of `bootmgfw.efi`.
- Download and install my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) program. There are several ways to do this, each with its own quirks and caveats. If you can get your non-booting installation to boot, say by using [Super GRUB 2 Disk,](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) installing the Debian package is likely (but not certain) to succeed. Depending on how it's installed, rEFInd may be able to boot Linux directly, without the use of GRUB.

Comment: In the log, we can see that efibootmgr has been used successfully by grub-efi/Boot-Repair, so it is likely to be a firmware that violates the UEFI specs.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be a firmware that violates the UEFI specs.

To workaround this, run `Boot-Repair` --> `Advanced options` --> tick `Backup and rename EFI files` --> `Apply`. Indicate the new URL that will appear if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This has helped me a lot to find my own way. My boot-repair looked different though. Total sum of what I did to get GRUB for both windows 8 and Ubuntu.

- In Bios. Make boot menu look for regular HDD first before going to Windows Boot.
- Load into Ubuntu.
- Follow the post to install and use boot-repair

Only for me it didn't show the options shown. On GRUB location I had minimal options.

**OS to load to** : Here I chose : Windows (Via sd5 window) <--sda5 is partition of my Ubuntu

**Sperate/bot/efi partition :** : sda2 <-- sda2 is partition of my Windows.

Pop up window followed asking me to fix Windows boot ->> I clicked yes.

Now on startup it will load Ubuntu GRUB and go automatically to windows after 10 seconds unless I choose Ubuntu. I hope that I have made it clear, and hope I can help at least one person.

Answer (score 0):

1. F12 while ubuntu is loading
2. Repair mode
3. Grub
4. wait
5. reboot