# Upgrade 13.10 to 14.04 broke grub - now boots straight to Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, boot-repair

Upgraded from a functioning dual-boot Window 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. Before today at startup I option to choose Ubuntu or Windows8.1.

The default was Ubuntu, and if I waited a few seconds Ubuntu 13.10 would start with no action. Now machine boots straight to windows bypassing the old grub screen.

From Bios if I choose the right drive I get three options to boot to: Windows ubuntu Ubuntu, I can choose the last one and I am able to get Ubuntu 14.04 up. Installed boot repair and ran it info here:http://paste.ubuntu.com/7293152/ .... Would like to get the old boot screen....

Pls help.

Comment: Do you see the "GRUB loading / Welcome to GRUB" message?

Comment: No. At startup it bypasses grub and straight to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) from your Ubuntu installation, if you are lucky you will be able to revert and re-order your boot entries from there.

Comment: Ran Grub Customizer, it didn't change anything. Its almost as if there are two copies of Grub? Note the options to choose ubuntu or Ubuntu from bios.

Comment: Then you should try to re-install the GRUB loader, as someone already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If normal 'Recommended Repair' of Boot-Repair does not solve your problem , you can try 'purging and re-installing grub' by selecting one of the options in 'Advanced Options' of boot-repair .

Click "Advanced Options" -> Select "Grub Options" tab -> Tick the "Purge GRUB and reinstall it" option --> Apply

For more details check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: OK. Is this high risk?

Comment: You can try it but read the "Purging & Reinstalling GRUB 2" section in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing before starting.

Comment: Thanks it didn't seem to change anything. I tried it and I get an error message from boot-repair at the end....

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: The information is posted here I think: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7294250/ I only see the last lines on a final window before I am asked to restart.

Comment: I noticed in boot-repair advanced Grub Options tab the Secure boot is ticked. Meanwhile that is turned off in my bios, maybe turning it off will help?

Comment: yes you can try it.

Comment: Still not booting Ubuntu - straight to Windows but now have Windows and Ubuntu as the options through bios. Before I had: Windows, ubuntu and Ubuntu. Boot repair says: The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: Ext 4 50Gigs exists already.

Comment: Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327676/dual-boot-menu-with-ubuntu-and-windows-8-not-showing-up

Comment: I could not change the boot order from BIOS as indicated at that link but did run Boot-Repair --> Advanced Options --> tick the Backup and rename the Windows EFI files option --> Apply. To no avail....thanks for your help so far. Still boots windows without showing grub.

Comment: Does this tell you anything? From grub customizer: recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  766dbf2a-d437-4ab5-a521-8c6a8b48e0b5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 766dbf2a-d437-4ab5-a521-8c6a8b48e0b5
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=766dbf2a-d437-4ab5-a521-8c6a8b48e0b5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic

Comment: Check the solution at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot?rq=1

Comment: This WAS the solution! Woo hoo! Check the solution at this link: askubuntu.com/questions/371559/…