# Unable to see dual boot screen

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on win 8 machine and it was dual boot option and now I donot see the dual boot screen to select which OS to boot
and only windows is booting up automatically.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does pressing the Esc key give you an option to see the dual boot screen? Please check the following link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/327676/dual-boot-menu-with-ubuntu-and-windows-8-not-showing-up

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair, by booting into Ubuntu from Live-USB or Live-DVD.

Install  'boot repair' with Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) by typing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Run/Open 'boot-repair':

```
sudo boot-repair
```

Click on 'Recommended repair' and write on a piece of paper the new URL that will appear.

Finally, reboot your PC!

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your ubuntu system then locate and check:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

See if it contains the both operating systems (Ubuntu and Windows).

Run from the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the system and see if you can boot into your OS.