# Installed both Ubuntu 12.04 and SolydX but no grub menu

Tags: grub2

I recently downloaded both isos of Ubuntu 12.04 and SolydX OS and played the live image and then installed with my hard drive partitioned for both of them. My problem is that I look at disc management under Windows 8, and all of the partitions assigned for the OS's say 100% free space and when I boot up, there is no GRUB menu. Can it be that my laptop has the haswell processor which meant new motherboard, or can it mean something else?

Comment: Could you go in more details how you installed the OS's? Like the order of installation, what options you used, what have you tried in order to repair it? Every (relevant) action is important.

Answer (score 0):

**[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240496/how-to-show-grub-after-install-ubuntu-over-windows-8)** outlines a similar problem to yours, but without mentioning what they see under the "disk management" section in Windows.

Note that I believe your partitions are shown as 100% free because Windows can't read the ext# filesystem that Linux employs. Therefore, it would make sense that they either display as 100% free or 100% used. As long as your partitions **exist**, I would not be too concerned with what the Windows Disk Management utility tells you.