# I want to install 12.04 in asus k55vd-sx313r

Tags: system-installation

Recently I bought "asus k55vd-sx313r". Earlier I am using Lenovo G570. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in Lenovo by choosing "Something Else" option, Keeping 2 Gb for Swap 10Gb for Root And 5Gb for Home. After Restart normally windows is opening, but Ubuntu is not detected. Even though hard partitions remain a new drives 10gb and 5gb.

Comment: You sure no other error happened when you installed? Also, what version of windows are you using

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Home Basic ....No other error i found...After installing ubuntu , i am unable to laod it

Comment: Did you try boot-repair?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240496/how-to-show-grub-after-install-ubuntu-over-windows-8
It hepled me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with boot repair.

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from

**System->Administration->Boot-Repair** menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity