# Dual-boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows

I have install Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. But when I am turning on my computer, ubuntu boots automatically and i can not boot windows.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your question with the results.

Comment: Try this solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240496/how-to-show-grub-after-install-ubuntu-over-windows-8) You have to fix the GRUB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold shift as you see the BIOS screen until you get a list of bootable Operating Systems. If Windows isn't there, you have probably accidentally removed it...

Answer (score 0):

try running `osprober` see if it detects your windows.
Also while installing did go into your bios and disabled `fast boot` or `secure boot`.
Might be a UEFI issue.