# GNU Grub not loading by default

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, gnu

I have dual booted my machine. First I had installed Windows 8.1, and then I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.03 version. I had switched off secured boot and power boot options . Now when I boot my machine, Windows boot loader directly starts the Windows 8.1, and I am not getting the GNU Grub option where I can select the OS to be booted. I need to press F9 and select the boot loader and then I am being directed to GNU Grub. Now how can I resolve this issue so that GNU Grub loads by default and I do not need to press F9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show GRUB after install Ubuntu over Windows 8?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240496/how-to-show-grub-after-install-ubuntu-over-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Make_the_firmware_launch_GRUB2_.28U.29EFI_as_default

A other idea would be to enter the UEFI and change the boot order.